# sql server year

Tags: sql-server

DECLARE @FINANCIALYEAR AS varchar(30)
    DECLARE @FINALFINANCIALYEAR AS int

```
SELECT @FINANCIALYEAR=CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-2) + ', ' +  
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + ', ' +  
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())) 

set @FINALFINANCIALYEAR = CONVERT(int,@FINANCIALYEAR)
print @FINALFINANCIALYEAR
```

i want final output in int format so iam doing above code but it gives me error plz help

Comment: Yes, you're constructing a list of three numbers, separated by commas, and then trying to convert that into a single int. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? - what are you going to do with your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-2) + ', ' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + ', ' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select YEAR (GetDate())-2,YEAR (GetDate())-1, YEAR (GetDate())
```

Comment: Neat - I always use DATEPART myself - I'd not encountered the YEAR function before.  I shall use that from now on!

Answer (score 1):

Just check what your variable is after your SELECT:

```
DECLARE @FINANCIALYEAR AS varchar(30)
DECLARE @FINALFINANCIALYEAR AS int

SELECT @FINANCIALYEAR=CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-2) + ', ' +  
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + ', ' +  
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())) 

SELECT @FINANCIALYEAR
```

The output is:

```
2008, 2009, 2010
```

This is clearly **NOT** a valid INT value - so it's obvious you're getting a conversion error.....

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 1, DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 2`

Answer (score 0):

this year is

```
Select datepart(year,getdate())
```

or

```
year(getdate())
```