# SQL Server types conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql server year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757670/sql-server-year)

**EXACT** duplicate of [sql server year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757670/sql-server-year)

```
DECLARE @FINANCIALYEAR AS varchar(30) 
DECLARE @FINALFINANCIALYEAR AS int 

SELECT @FINANCIALYEAR=CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-2) + ', ' +   
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + ', ' +   
CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE()))  

set @FINALFINANCIALYEAR = CONVERT(int,@FINANCIALYEAR) 
print @FINALFINANCIALYEAR
```

i want final output in int format so i'am doing above code but it gives me error plz help

Comment: **WHAT** error does it give you?!?!?!

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [sql server year ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757670/sql-server-year)

Comment: Yes, you're constructing a list of three numbers, separated by commas, and then trying to convert that into a single int. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? - what are you going to do with your result?

Comment: lol @marc_s adding "EXACT duplicate" to the question title..hahah

Answer (score 0):

FINANCIALYEAR is a string contains something like "2008,2009,2010". Then you trying to convert in to int. Obviously it will fail.

Comment: FINANCIALYEAR contains OVER 9000!!!!!!!!!!!!!!